# How do I switch between normal mode and VR mode during runtime?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Android 4.4 Unity 5.6 Google VR SDK 1.7. I have followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pA3NB9OZppo to switch between vr and normal modes during runtime but normal screen become stretched out and doesn't look like what it originally is. How do I properly do this in Unity3d?

Comment: What is SDK? details

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the unclear format or whatever, but for anyone stuck in this problem I found my own answer here at the sdk forum. 
https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/wiki/Switching-between-VR-and-non-VR-at-runtime